# How to add dynamic attribute to an Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to add dynamic attribute to an object, for example I use the following code to add index (`index`)attribute to `myObj`, `index` is a variable.

```
var myObj={};
for(var index=0; index<10; index++){
   myObj[index]='my'+index;
}
```

But it does not work...

Comment: That should work, but you're not very clear about what you expect the result to be.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript events or with jQuery. And, so far as I can tell, it *does* work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If what you *really* want is for "myObj" to have properties like "my0", "my1", through "my10", then what you want is

```
for (var index = 0; index < 10; ++index)
  myObj['my' + index] = something;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an object with {}, use [] since you are creating a simple array.

```
var myObj=[];
for(var index=0; index<10; index++){
   myObj[index]='my'+index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you can try using :

```
myObj[index+""]='my'+index;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a number as a property name in JavaScript in the same way you use a string.

Using myObj[1] will return the property value you're looking for, but myObj.1 will not.

It would be best to use a string like @Pointy and @sudimail recommended.